# Keycloak Gatekeeper 7.0.0 multiple client Id skip-client-id option

Tags: keycloak-gatekeeper

In older versions of Keycloak Gatekeeper, there was the option

```
   --skip-client-id                          skip the check on the client token (default: false)
```

I am using Keycloak Gatekeeper 7.0.0, where the option has been removed.
My problem is, I am using microservices with MULTIPLE client Id. But as I understood, the gatekeeper only supports 1 client Id.

The question is:
How can I configure the Gatekeeper to accept multiple client Id requests?

The documentation is not giving any hints for that.

Does anyone faced the same problem?

Thanks in advance!